# How to move to the tag with has specific class name from a current caret

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am writing the program which searches HTML.

I wrapped in the searched keyword with the span tag which has 'find' class beforehand like this:

```
<b><span class="find">A</span>
    <i>B</i>C</b>DDD<b><span class="find">A</span></span><i>B</i>C</b>
```

When "next" or "prev" button clicks, I would like to move to the nearest next/prev span tag from a current selection point(I got from `window.getSelection()`).

if `"jQuery(selection.focusNode).next('.find');"` can be used for it, I will solve it simply, but it is invalid. Are there any good method?

Comment: selection.focusNode.parentNode might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like that :

```
var foo = {
    spans: $('span.find'),
    pos: -1,
    getSpan: function(inc) {
        var pos = this.pos + inc;
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < this.spans.length) {
            this.pos = pos;
            return this.spans[this.pos];
        }
        return undefined;
    },
    next: function() {
        var span = this.getSpan(1);
        // do what you have to do with it
    },
    prev: function() {
        var span = this.getSpan(-1);
        // do what you have to do with it
    },
}
```

and then 'connect' *next* and *prev* to your buttons.

It is what your are looking for ?

Comment: The basis of movement is a current selection. In short, I would like to implement "Find Next" and "Find Prev".

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sLwuN/

**Javascript**

```
$("#prev").click(function(){
    foundElement($(getSelection().focusNode.parentNode).prevAll('.find').first());
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    foundElement($(getSelection().focusNode.parentNode).nextAll('.find').first());
});

function foundElement ($element) {
    if ($element) {
        $element.css('color', 'red');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $element.css('color', 'inherit');
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="find">A</span>
<i>BBBBB</i>
<span class="find">B</span>
<span class="find">CC</span>
<i>CCCCCC</i>
<span class="find">D</span>

<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying. It works well on FireFox and Chrome. But IE10 doesn't work...